# Shortcut to find the cube and square of a square matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, education

I found myself doing the same task repetitively so I was wondering if there is a short formula or generalized equation that can give me the square or cube of a matrix ($A\cdot A$ or $A\cdot A \cdot A$) without having to multiply it by itself again and again. Could not find anything on the internet related to this.

Comment: It depends on the matrix, but no, there is no general way of doing easier

Comment: For higher powers than 3 you can use repeated squaring

Comment: Diagonalising the matrix (in the form $A = PDP^{-1}$) does not work unless you have a convenient set of numbers. The numbers in most exercises are convenient, but if you're doing this for practical purposes you won't be able to do this without involving radicals. Being able to do mental arithmetic quickly helps, but you will also get better with practice.

Comment: If you can code, why don't you implement Mathematica?

Comment: I can , but i was looking for some written method, as I found a shortcut or a trick to do almost anything repetitive and tiring in maths for my exams but I could not find a method for this except the formerly mentioned repeated squaring method

Answer (score 1):

The Cayley-Hamilton Theorem can be useful. It states that every matrix obeys its own characteristic polynomial. Finding the polynomial is not trivial, but once you have it you have a quicker way to find higher powers. The advantage is that you only have to multiply by a constant and add.

Comment: Well, aren’t you somewhat capped as to the powers you can find? The characteristic polynomial limits you to finding through CH at most the $n$th power, where $n$ is the size of the square matrix

Comment: @FShrike No, you can keep multiplying by the matrix to get a recursive equation for higher powers. So if, say you have $M^2+3M-2I=0$ you can rearrange this as $M^2=-3M+2I$ and keep multiplying by $M$ to get $M^3=-3M^2+2M$ and $M^4=-3M^3+2M^2$ and $M^{n+2}=-3M^{n+1}+2M^n$